# Bash variable SECONDS expanded immediately or delayed?

Tags: bash

If I have a line that operates on the $SECONDS variable twice will that variable hold the same value since it's on the same line?

For example consider a simple line like `echo $SECONDS $SECONDS` or `echo $((SECONDS/60)) minutes and $((SECONDS%60)) seconds`.

Will SECONDS always be the same value since they are on the same line? In other words, does it get expanded right before the line is executed? When exactly does $SECONDS get expanded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are expanded before passing to `echo`, if that's what you are asking. However, the 2 instances of `$SECONDS` will be evaluated separately, AFAIK. So in case, when the `seconds` tick has crossed the value between 2 evaluations, you will see 2 different values.

Try this:

```
i=0;
while true; do
    read a b <<< "$SECONDS $SECONDS";
    ((i++));
    ((a!=b)) && printf "Iteration %-8d : %d %d\n" $i $a $b;
done

Iteration 3517346    : 467 468
Iteration 4157710    : 488 489
Iteration 4240219    : 491 492
```

Comment: Great illustration!

Comment: Thank you. The code helped. I was able to reproduce in Ubuntu.

Comment: This example also shows that the evaluation happens from left to right... :-D

Comment: Do you happen to know if it's guaranteed to happen left to right?

Comment: I don't have a proof that it is guaranteed. But based on the output above, it appears to be happening this way.

Comment: The POSIX standard specifies that both arithmetic expansions and command substitutions occur at the same time, "beginning to end" (which I think refers to the order in which they are identified during parsing, which means left to right). Something like `echo $((SECONDS)) $(sleep 2) $((SECONDS))` would seemingly be required to show different values for `SECONDS` to keep with its defined behavior.